# SQL query that looks within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Apologies - am not good at SQL. Perhaps this is a simple query - I don't know.

What I have is a basic forum table - e.g.

```
id poster title type content postedon parentID
```

in this scheme, if a user asks a question, it is type = 0, and if it is an answer, type = 1. If the entry is an answer, I update the parentID to the id on the question row.

All I want to do is pull the questions in a SQL query, along with a number that has the total number of answers to the question - for e.g. a result row would look like

```
jerry@dumb.com "how do I do this?" 4
```

Where (4) would be the total answers to my question. I want to do this in a single query - without having to pull the questions first, and then run repeated queries for each question Id to find the count of the answers.

How do I do this?

Thank you all,

(PS - is there a way to do the query in Linq expressions? I would do that instead of a stored procedure if I could)

Comment: Do you want to see questions with zero answers?

Comment: Yes! Joe's answer almost did it, and I posted asking exactly that. I need all questions returned, and they may have 0 or more answers.

Comment: additionally, will your title of the answers change compared to the title of the question. Eg: it is possible that the title has a Re: XYZ for a original title of XYZ or is that not an issue here?

Comment: @In Sane - titles will not change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select ft1.poster, ft1.title, count(ft2.id)
    from ForumTable ft1
        left join ForumTable ft2
            on ft1.id = ft2.parentID
                and ft2.type = 1
    where ft1.type = 0
    group by ft1.poster, ft1.title
```

Comment: Joe - that seems to (almost) do it. But it returns only rows where the question had 1 or more answers, but not those that have none (0 answers)...what do I modify?

Comment: tried that, and I get a '1' for all the questions that had no answers... (the parentID column is filled with 0 for all questions)

Comment: Yeah, realized my mistake too. You want to left join and count from the second table. See edited answer.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. And sorry I can't 'vote you up', still a student on Stackoverflow, you see!

Comment: came back to this question a year-and-half later just so I could up-vote you ;)

Comment: @jeremy Now that's dedication!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see if it meets your needs?

```
SELECT poster, title, ISNULL(X.NoOfAnswers,0)
FROM forum LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT parentId, COUNT(id) as NoOfAnswers
FROM forum
GROUP BY parentId) X
ON forum.id = X.parentId
WHERE forum.type = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.poster, a.acontent, COUNT(B.parentId) AS Answers 
FROM forum B, forum A 
WHERE B.atype = 1 AND B.parentId = A.id 
GROUP BY a.id, a.poster, a.acontent
```